# Error during LWC component connect phase: [Maximum call stack size exceeded]

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lwc-dom, constructor

I am trying to assign value to a property of my parent component's constructor method.
Below is the html code:

```
<template>
   {welcomes}
 
<c-testfile></c-testfile>
    </template>
```

Below is the js code:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class testfile extends LightningElement {

    constructor() {
        console.log('inside constructor');
        super();
        this.welcomes='mine';
    }

}
```

I am calling this lwc component from an aura component and when I am running the aura app, the constructor is called multiple times and I am getting the below error:

[image]

Why the constructor is called multiple times here?

Answer (score -1):

My bad. I was calling the same parent component in my HTML as a child component. Hence it's going in a recursive mode.